# How to add a vector layers to my map using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector, web-mapping

I'm trying to add a vector layer manually to my map but i receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: b.attachEvent is not a function 
the code is :

```
// adding data 
// Define Geometries

var point = new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.transform([10.8,36.7],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')
);
var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(
    ol.proj.transform([10.8,36.7],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
    600000
);
// features
var pointFeature = new ol.Feature(point);
var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
// source
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG: 4326'
});
vectorSource.addFeature([pointFeature,circleFeature]);
//vector Layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
// add layer to the map
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I can't resolve it. [image]

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336695/adding-vector-layers-to-map-using-openlayers

Comment: Yes It's me. I post the question again with my last account to find a solution.

Comment: The problem in the line "vectorSource.addFeatures([pointFeature,circleFeature]);" add s to feature